# Apache Camel's "httpClientConfigurer" is impacting all the URLs and not just the URL on which it is specified

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

I am using Apache Camel's producer-template to invoke a 3rd party HTTP URL. I am doing something like this:

```
producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("http://example.com?httpClientConfigurer=myCustomHttpClientConfigurer", "", requestHeaders, String.class)
```

This works perfectly. All the configurations done in "myCustomHttpClientConfigurer" work properly. So far so good.

Then using the same producer-template object, I do the following:

```
producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("http://example2.com", "", requestHeaders, String.class)
```

Here, please note that I am not specifying a httpClientConfigurer but still, whatever settings I specified in "myCustomHttpClientConfigurer" are coming into effect. So, basically, once I configure a httpClientConfigurer for one URL, it automatically becomes available for other URLs that are invoked afterwards.

How do I configure a "httpClientConfigurer" only for one particular URL?

Camel Version: 2.9.2

Comment: That is a very old version of Camel. Try with new version.